# Different coordinates while resizing an imageview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, image-resizing

I'm trying to resizing an imageview using these functions:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* mTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_01]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
        NSLog(@"questo è x");
        NSLog(@"lalal %f", cp.y);

        if (cp.y > 390) {

            [_Logo_01 setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (cp.y < 130) {
            [_Logo_01 setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (cp.x > 290) {
            [_Logo_01 setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (cp.x < 40) {
            [_Logo_01 setHidden:YES];
        }

    }
```

when i resize my Logo on the app the image resizes correctly but my center point is wrong

I'm sorry i wronged to post code
this is the code that i use to scale my images:

```
- (IBAction)ScaleImage1:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;

    CGFloat height = _Logo_01.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"SIZE ===== %f", height);
    if (height > 600) {
        [_Logo_01 setHidden:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try to write same style everywhere (brackets written randomly, spaces, newlines) - it's easier to read and shows that the dev is better.
2. `Logo_01` is just horrible name for UI element. It's good for asset name. Refactor and rename it to eg `startingLogoImageView`.
3. Comparing views with `==` and `isEqual` works in a different way. One compares pointers, other one objects. Please read about it, as that's a serious bug if that's unintended.
4. What is `xd` in `setCenter:` line? Where is it from?
5. We try not to use shortcuts in Objective-C. You should name `cp` `touchPoint` as it's more obvious what it is in fact. That's the way recommended by Apple and used by devs.

So the code:

```
// extern NSUInteger const kViewOffsetY; // uncomment this line if you want it accessible via other classes, delete otherwise
NSUInteger const kViewOffsetY = 1;
NSUInteger const kViewOffsetX = 1;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isEqual:startingLogoImageView]) {
        UIView *touchedView = touch.view;
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        [touchedView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(touchedView.frame) - kViewOffsetX, CGRectGetMidY(touchedView.frame) - kViewOffsetY)];

        // where are these values from? you probably should calculate it more dynamically
        BOOL shouldHideView = touchPoint.y > 390 || touchPoint.y < 130 || touchPoint.x > 290 || touchPoint.x < 40;
        if (shouldHideView) {
            [touchedView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Why was it working wrong? Because in `setCenter:` method you were using top left corner (`x` and `y` values of view are in top left corner not in the center), while you should use the center point.

Comment: @Mark Updated code works fine with my fixes. You should just fix all invalid name etc bugs. In obj-c we write method names will small letter, not capital.